# Webpack Error: read is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, webpack, redux

I am trying to build a full stack web application that uses React, Redux, Socket.io and some other dependencies.

Here is the package.json file for a full list of dependencies

```
{
  "name": "react-voting-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.8.3",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I am using webpack to bundle the files together. I created the react app using create-react-app.

When I try to run the application, I get the following error

> index.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: read is not a function(…)

and a bunch of other warnings from socket.io

> Critical dependencies: 1:475-482 This seems to be a pre-built
>   javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to
>   require the original source to get better results
>
> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bufferutil' in
>   /Users/zaidhumayun/Desktop/React/react-voting-app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib
>
> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'utf-8-validate' in
>   /Users/zaidhumayun/Desktop/React/react-voting-app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib

Initially, I was getting another error which stated that

> Critical dependencies: 75:43-65 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @ ./~/socket.io/~/engine.io/lib/server.js 75:43-65

However, I got rid of this error by uninstall socket.io@1.6.0 and installing socket.io@1.4.4 as suggested by this github issue

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/212

But, what happened was that the warning was just replaced with a different one. The first one given in the previous list.

After looking through the stack trace of the original error where it says, read is not a function(screenshot of the stack trace below), it looks like the error is in the read module not being required properly or not importing correctly. [image: Screenshot of the stack trace for the error]

Here are the two lines of code pertinent to the issue I found in Server.serverClient

```
var read = __webpack_require__(/*! fs */ 323).readFileSync;

clientSource = read(/*require.resolve*/(/*! socket.io-client/socket.io.js */ 468), 'utf-8');
```

The second line is where the error appears.

I am guessing this has something to do with the third warning which stated the module utf-8-validate could not be resolved.

How do I fix this issue? Or is there a workaround to it?

Comment: Whenever I run into these somewhat odd issues I make sure Im on the latest Node.js, remove node_modules, and do a fresh `npm install`

Comment: @cgatian - Yeah, I tried that. Didn't do anything for me. I'm still stuck with the same errors